# c#/java Drag points and draw lines between them

Tags: c#, draw, lines, point

Hey,
is there a a simple way in c# or java to let the user "drop" points onto the form and then draw lines between the new point and existing ones ?

with simple way i mean a component/framework/whatever (or even already existend in c#/java ?)

Comment: C# *or* Java? Suggest you focus the question on one or the other, as their frameworks/libraries are different. Is this for WinForms, WPF, or web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure; it'll be framework and architecture dependent though. C# WPF will have a different way to do it then C# WinForms which will be different than Java Swing.

For Winforms, you'll simply create a Graphics object based on some area of your form bounded by a control (like a Panel or PictureBox), then on that Control's MouseClick event, log the mouse's current location and draw a line between that location and the location of the previous click (or all other clicks).

If you want to drag and drop, like from a toolbar, that's a little more complex; basically you need to track what you dragged and where you dropped it so when you drop it you can perform the proper action. I believe the arguments you'll get in the DragDrop handler will give you this information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any lib that does that, but what I did to simplify things a bit is created usercontrol 2x2 which represented a point and allowed user to drop it onto form by drag and drop.  Lines were drawn manually, however, in OnPaint(...)

Comment: would you share the sources ? (maybe even a simple example application ?)

Comment: Not promising anything, but I'll find it in myarchive, I'll posst it.  Actually it's quite easy in c# (don't know about java).